# Find and replace using regex in sed

Tags: regex, sed, unix

I want to replace

```
# Bulk Delete #
```

with

```
=== Bulk Delete ===
```

I am using the following `sed` command.

```
sed "s/#\([^#]*\)#/===\1===/g" filename
```

It works, but it also replaces

```
### Translation
```

with

```
======# Translation
```

How to prevent it and make it work in both mac and ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `+` to enforce at least one character which is not a `#`

Since the `sed` in OSX does not support the enhanced regular expression syntax like `+` by default, you need to pass the `-E` flag to sed. And the good news is `-E` flag works well on `*nix` systems too. When using the `-E` flag, you can skip escaping the special regex characters like `+`, `(`, etc.

```
sed -E "s/#([^#]+)#/===\1===/g" filename
```

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - updated the answer. Try with the `-E -e` flag, should work on both `OSX` and `*nix`

Comment: The `-e` option universally (meaning all versions of `sed`) specifies that the next argument is part of the script; you can specify it multiple times to build up a complex script.  On Mac OS X, you can use the `-E` option to invoke 'extended regular expressions', but then you don't need the backslashes: `sed -E -e 's/#([^#]+#/===\1===/g'`.

Comment: Yes you're right about, `-e` which was optional. Should have mentioned that.

Comment: OK—we're in agreement on Mac.  I'm not sure about elsewhere.  According to its help message, GNU `sed` (4.4.2) uses the `-r` option to invoke extended regular expressions.  However, it seems to support `-E` as an undocumented synonym for `-r`.

Comment: I tried it on my Linux box with `GNU sed version 4.2.1` and it seems to be happy with `-E`. And yes you're right `-r` seems to be the option documented in the man page and I do not see `-E`. I'm not sure if the man page on my system is outdated.

Comment: I knew about the `-r` option, but didn't know about `-E`. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is to match the blanks too:

```
sed 's/# \([^#]*\) #/=== \1 ===/g' filename
```

Another way is to require multiple (one or more) non-hashes between the two hashes:

```
sed 's/#\([^#]\{1,\}\)#/===\1===/g' filename
```

The `\{n,m\}` is a quantifier notation that requires at least *n* occurrences and at most *m* occurrences of the pattern immediately before it, so it is generalization of the `?`, `*` and `+` metacharacters (which can be represented by `\{0,1\}`, `\{0,\}`, and `\{1,\}` respectively).  If *m* is missing, it means any number not smaller than *n*; if *n* is missing, it means any number not larger than *m*, and so is equivalent to 0.  In my example, I'm using it as the classic, portable (to prehistoric versions of `sed` off Linux and Mac OS X) version of `+`.

Another way of writing that is:

```
sed 's/#\([^#][^#]*\)#/===\1===/g' filename
```

And you can combine the ideas, of course:

```
sed 's/# \([^#][^#]*\) #/=== \1 ===/g' filename
sed 's/# \([^#]\{1,\}\) #/=== \1 ===/g' filename
```

Comment: Can you kindly explain `'s/#\([^#]\{1,\}\)#/===\1===/g'` a bit more, or point me to some documentation? I am slightly confused.